# using ajax The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, routes

I'm trying to add a review to the database using ajax, but laravel gives an error. What to do? P.S @method('PUT') I tried, php artisan clear:cache didn't help either

**Blade**

```
<form action="#" class="sendcomment" method="POST">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_name" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="50" rows="10">
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> 
            </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/comment_add',
      data: data,
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert( "" );
        }
      },
      complete: (function(response) { 

         if(response.responseText == 'ok') {
        }
        else {
    
          console.log('ERROR');
        }
      }),
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

**Route**

`Route::post('/comment_add','Admin\CommentController@addcomment');`

**Controller**

```
public function addcomment(Request $request)
   {
           return 'ok';
   }
```

@method('PUT') I tried, php artisan clear:cache didn't help either

I want to add a review to the database using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your route a name like this :

```
Route::post('/comment_add','Admin\CommentController@addcomment')->name('post.addcomment');
```

inside your ajax code define the route using the route helper like this:

```
type:"post",
url:'{{route('post.addcomment')}}',
```

and before you send the request you need to setup your xcrf token like this :

```
 $.ajaxSetup(
          {
            headers:{
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("[name='_token']").val(),
            }
          }
        );
```

so your full ajax code will be like the following:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajaxSetup(
              {
                headers:{
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("[name='_token']").val(),
                }
              }
            );
    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: '{{route('post.addcomment')}}',
      data: data,
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert( "" );
        }
      },
      complete: (function(response) { 

         if(response.responseText == 'ok') {
        }
        else {
    
          console.log('ERROR');
        }
      }),
    });
```